# SingleChildScrollView still causes the screen to overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a simple screen built using the code shown below. I want to keep the ad banner at the top at all times while the `Container()` below it to be scrollable. This is the reason I put `SingleChildScrollView()` in the lower container.

But it still overflows the screen with the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 162 pixels on the bottom.
```

This is what the screen looks like:

[image]

```
body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            // colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.color),
            image: AssetImage("assets/feathers_bg.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AdmobBanner(
              //below is test id
              adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
              adSize: AdmobBannerSize.FULL_BANNER,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.network(_birdDetails.thumbnail.source),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              _birdName,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.teal,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              _birdDetails.description,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          _birdDetails.extract,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR version. Your SingleChildScrollView needs to be Expanded (you can put Expanded -> Padding - > SingleChildScrollView).

Longer version you can read in the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), this section describes a similar scenario:

> One common reason for this to happen is that the Column has been
> placed in another Column (without using Expanded or Flexible around
> the inner nested Column). When a Column lays out its non-flex children
> (those that have neither Expanded or Flexible around them), it gives
> them unbounded constraints so that they can determine their own
> dimensions (passing unbounded constraints usually signals to the child
> that it should shrink-wrap its contents). The solution in this case is
> typically to just wrap the inner column in an Expanded to indicate
> that it should take the remaining space of the outer column, rather
> than being allowed to take any amount of room it desires.

And here is a bit simplified version of your code that is easily reproducible (to paste and run for example in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'SO Question : 64200763'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StringBuffer birdDetails;
  var rng = new Random();
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    birdDetails = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<4000; i++){
      birdDetails.write(String.fromCharCode(rng.nextInt(25) + 97));
      if(rng.nextBool() && rng.nextBool()) birdDetails.write(' ');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100, 
              width: double.maxFinite,
              color: Colors.yellow, 
              child: Text('Ad placeholder', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
            ),
            Expanded( 
              child: Padding(  // Here is your fix, place expanded above the SingleChildScrollView
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Image.network('https://picsum.photos/id/1024/512/288'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Bird name',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Colors.teal,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Bird (random) description',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            birdDetails.toString(),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),       
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

End result (as per how you organized the widgets, but without overflows):

[image: end result gif]

PS, before posting a question I highly recommend stripping / replacing the code of all dependencies that some users might or might not have at hand (like AdMob), unnecessary assets (like AssetImage) and lastly class structures that aren't defined in the question (like birdDetails.thumbnail.source). It might help you debug the problem on your own and if it doesn't it makes it easier for people that are trying to help you ;).

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful reply. and I'll make sure to make my code dartpad friendly next time I post :)